# Validate Rails Simple Form For with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

[image]The problem is that the form name is auto generated as "topic[l1_keywords][]" and that appears to be invalid. I tried to follow this fiddle to no avail. http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/

Form

```
= simple_form_for @topic, :remote => true, :html=> { class: 'topics-form'} do |f|
      .small-12.keywords
        .small-3.columns.l1kw
          %label
            Level 1 Keywords:
            = generic_tooltip("Start with a broad focus--use synonyms. EG, 'agriculture', 'farming'")
          =f.input :l1_keywords, required: true, as: :string, label:false, input_html: {class: "select2 topics-select",
            multiple: "multiple", :"data-tags" => "", placeholder: 'agriculture, farming'}
```

JS

```
$('#new_topic').validate({
    rules: {
        topic[l1_keywords]: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: Attached screenshot if it helps. Shows JS error.

Comment: di you try adding name attribute to the input field?

Comment: That helps/works. Thank you!